# Pizza Dough Ingredients too runny even after adding flour

Tags: dough, pizza

My husband is trying to make pizza dough as I speak. He prepared the yeast properly. After adding all of the ingredients, he claims the mixture is runny on the top and thick and gooey on the bottom. I am at a standstill as to how to save this dough. He added more flour.

Can the dough still be salvaged?

Comment: Can you give us the ratios and method, please? And perhaps include a photo or two? That would probably give you better answers, as it stands, trying to amswer is a bit "stabbing in the dark". And while you wait for answers, let me point you to our [tour] and [help], where you'll learn more about the site. Welcome to Seasoned Advice!

Comment: Hello Jo, a large part of your post was unrelated to the dough batch you are trying to save, and your conclusion also contributed nothing to the question except for being unfriendly to your husband. We are glad to have your culinary question, so I reduced the text to describe the relevant part only. Still, as Stephie says, with so little information, I doubt that we can tell you much more. You neither tell us the ingredients, nor the proportions, nor at which stage it was so problematic. Also note that a question shouldn't be a rant in disguise, http://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: "runny on top and think and gooey on the bottom" sounds like a mixing issue.  Are you mixing by hand or using an appliance?

Answer (score 2):

Personal results, I have never been able to satisfactory save a yeast dough once it has gone wrong.  I have gotten them back to the point of almost seeming right, but it was an illusion, once cooked they were typically like a raw floured lump of baked brick.  Now, if I go wrong, I toss and start over.

Soupy to me sounds like something is likely off on the recipe and liquid is out of proportion would be my first guess.  Verify the units were right, no substituting cups for tablespoons (yes I have), and if you did not misread, try a different recipe.  Also, if you did not, try proofing your yeast first, which will help activate it and make sure it is still viable.  If after 10 minutes in warm water and a pinch of sugar you are not getting bubbles and a nice yeast smell it is likely dead and that is your culprit.